# Karma/Jasmine directive testing dom compiles but can't access it

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have been trying to figure out a way to test the `focusElement` function of my directive. But somehow, whenever I call the function in my test, the `classElements` variable is undefined. Anybody have a clue?

Here is the directive function

```
        $scope.focusElement = function() {
            if (attrs.focusToClass) {
                $scope.classElements = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.' + attrs.focusToClass));

                if (attrs.focusToClassIndex) {
                    // Focus to the class with the specified index.
                    // Index should be within the length of elements and must not be a negative number.
                    if (attrs.focusToClassIndex < $scope.classElements.length && attrs.focusToClassIndex >= 0) {
                        $scope.elementToFocus = $scope.classElements[attrs.focusToClassIndex];
                    }
                } else {
                    // Goes to the first index if the index is not specified.
                    $scope.elementToFocus = $scope.classElements[0];
                }
            } else if (attrs.focusToId) {
                // Focus to the given ID
               $scope.elementToFocus = angular.element(document.querySelector('#' + attrs.focusToId))[0];
            }

            if ($scope.elementToFocus) {
                $scope.elementToFocus.focus();
            }
        }
```

Here is the unit test code.

```
describe('focusElement function', function () {
    var targetElement;
    var element;
    var elementScope;
    var elementToFocus;

    beforeEach(function() {
        targetElement = $compile('<div id="targetDiv" class="targetClass"><span id="targetSpan" class="targetClass"></span></div>')($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });

    it('should return the class element with index 0', function() {
        element = $compile('<div next-focus focus-to-class="targetClass"></div>')($rootScope);
    });

    it('should return the class element with the specific index within the range', function() {
        element = $compile('<div next-focus focus-to-class="targetClass" focus-to-class-index="1"></div>')($rootScope);
    });

    it('should return the class element with the specific index outside the range', function() {
        element = $compile('<div next-focus focus-to-class="targetClass" focus-to-class-index="-1"></div>')($rootScope);
    });

    it('should return the id element', function() {
        element = $compile('<div next-focus focus-to-id="targetDiv"></div>')($rootScope);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        elementScope = element.scope();
        spyOn(elementScope, 'focusElement').and.callThrough();
        elementScope.focusElement();
        console.log(elementScope.classElements);

        expect(elementScope.focusElement).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(elementScope.elementToFocus).toBeDefined();
        expect(elementScope.elementToFocus.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlTwl.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error is the result of you using `document` directly in the code which comprises the unit under test. The solution is to refactor your code to not use `document` directly, rather use `jQuery` style `$()` syntax to get much the same behaviour, make the context which `$()` operates an injectable dependency and then in your unit test use things like `fixtures` to inject a well-known context during test. Since you are using Jasmine already, you probably want to look into [`jasmine-jquery`](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) for convenient API to do this easily.

(Alternatively, in this specific case you could also setup a stub/mock `document.querySelectorAll` in your `beforeEach()` callback.)

That's the where-does-the-issue-stem-from and the how-to-fix-it (high level) but it pays to understand Karma a bit better before proceeding.

Skipping over lots of finer points, basically karma consists of three things combined into one single application:

1. An extensible 'dummy' HTTP server to serve up content (as configured in `files`). This server is structured as an [Express JS](http://expressjs.com/) app, which is useful to remember if you ever want to integrate custom middleware. E.g. to expose additional paths on the server in order to, say, provide a dummy API server for your Angular app code to interact with. A particular path to remember is '/base' which corresponds to the project directory as defined in your Karma config (the working directory).
2. A driver to point a browser to a synthesied dummy 'index.html' kind of page on the HTTP server (which is how all entries in `files` for which `included: true` are loaded, basically as `<script>` tags).
3. An API/framework for integrating unit test logic, reporting, etc. This is where the `karma-jasmine` type plugins interact and also how Karma is able to get the output back out and determine whether tests succeeded or not.

Points #2 and #3 have implications, in particular that the environment (`window`) and the HTML (`document`) should essentially be treated as an internal implementation detail of Karma and are not to be relied on during tests. So that means your code under test also should not rely on these details either. This is why you should restructure your code to pass in the context for `$()` as a dependency and then you can pass a well-known fixture in your tests and the normal context in your actual app.